# Dynamic templateUrl in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

**Directives.js**

```
module.directive('vdGuarantees', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div ng-include="contentUrl"></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.contentUrl = '../../HTML/Directives/Guarantees/6787.html';
            scope.$watch(scope.clientId, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log(scope.clientId);
                //scope.contentUrl = '../../HTML/Directives/Guarantees/' + newValue + '.html'
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div vd-Guarantees></div>
```

In my controller i have defined `$scope.clientId` as an empty object. On load, the controller is doing an `$http` get request to a webservice and on `success` it populates `$scope.clientId`.

What i am trying to do is, when the clientId gets populated, change the templateUrl of the directive accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help of my brother i got the solution.

First mistake was the definition of my `$watch`. It should have been :

```
scope.$watch('clientId', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    //code here
});
```

Second thing i had to change was the scope object passed in the directive. So i added

```
scope: false
```

in the directive definition and that made the root scope to be available in the directive.

The full directive code now looks like:

```
module.directive('vdGuarantees', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div ng-include="contentUrl"></div>',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('clientId', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== undefined) {
                    scope.contentUrl = '../../HTML/Directives/Guarantees/' + newValue + '.html';
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```